# move visible button over invisible button

Tags: java, android

Ok, I don't speak good English so its going to be hard to explain what I want.

I have a custom dialog in Android with 2 `Buttons`

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="10dp">

        <Button android:id="@+id/button_ok"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_button_background_selector"
                style="@style/text_big_bold_inverted"
                android:text="@string/ok"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dialog_button_background_selector"
                style="@style/text_big_bold_inverted"
                android:text="@string/cancel"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Now sometimes I only need the OK `Button` and I make the cancel `Button` invisible.
But the OK `Button` stays at the left, is it possible to move the `Button` to the center when the other is invisible?

I tried using `.setGravity` but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the visibility of the Cancel button to View.GONE instead of View.VISIBLE.

Answer (score 1):

First set `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to your LinearLayout.

Then instead of View.INVISIBLE use View.GONE for Button.

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```